# Access html file in write mode using python

Tags: python

example.py

```
file = open("innovative.html", "w")
file.write("This is a test\n")
file.write("And here is another line\n")
file.close()
return render_template('innovative.html')
```

while I am executing this file in server it throwing [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'innovative.html'

I am executing this file in rhcloud.

I changed permissions for file as -rwx- for innovative.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the key will be that you're running it on a cloud provider - the current working directory of the script might not be the same one you've put innovative.html in. What happens when you put the full path to the file in the script?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when a file is actively opened or utilized by another  process at the same time (as well as when permissions are not given).  Be sure to check that the file is not being used while attempting to write.

Comment: I want it like rewrite the file like if we are opened a file in cpanel .. we are able to rewrite the code from cpanel like that.